# How to sort a multi-line list to a single-line list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would you take an output from the concatenation of two lists and put it into one list. For example-

```
example1 = ["hello", "banana", "skit"]   
example2 = ["rodeo", "pine", "sky", "feel"]   
joined_list = example1 + example2
```

But the outcome is like this-

```
[ "hello" ,   
  "banana" ,   
  "skit" ,   
  "rodeo" ,   
  "pine" ,   
  "sky" ,   
  "feel" ]
```

I need it to be in a one line list, so the output should look like-

`["hello", "banana", "skit", "rodeo", "pine", "sky", "feel"]`

If someone also knows how to sort this list based off highest string length to lowest, so it ends up looking like-

`["banana", "hello", "rodeo", "feel", "pine", "skit", "sky"]`

Any help into properly formatting this would be much appreciated!

Comment: `print(joined_list)`

Comment: joined_list = sorted (example1 + example2)

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'multi-line list'. The difference is how the list is being shown. Try the `print` function as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

use `sort`, on joined_list

```
example1 = ["hello", "banana", "skit"]   
example2 = ["rodeo", "pine", "sky", "feel"]   
joined_list = example1 + example2
joined_list.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
print(joined_list)
```

output

```
["banana", "hello", "rodeo", "feel", "pine", "skit", "sky"]
```

Comment: This is the right answer, and a huge time saver. In the Python 2.3 days you would use zip to combine a list of lengths with the list of strings, sort them (and reverse if necessary), and then unzip the sorted list to retrieve just the list of strings.

Comment: well, I joined python3.5 days, didn't know what happened in python2, but can understand your pain as I come from c++ background where I have to write this whole procedure, whereas it can be done in 1 line :D